# Joint "density" of data and indicators in Bayesian mixture model

Tags: probability, bayesian, finite-mixture-model

I'm currently working through the chapter on finite mixture models in
[BDA3](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/) and came across the
following model setup (with the usual slight abuse of notation):

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_H)$, $\sum_{h=1}^H\lambda_h = 1$ be the
mixing proportions and let $f(y_i\mid\theta_h)$ be some parametric density.

Then the observations $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ can be modeled as a continuous real-valued random variable with density

$$p(y\mid \theta,\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{h=1}^H \lambda_h f(y_i\mid\theta_h).$$

Alternatively we can introduce latent class indicators $z_{ih}$

$$z_{ih} = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if i-th observation is drawn from h-th mixture component} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

with distribution

$$z_i = (z_{i1},\dots,z_{iH}) \mid \lambda \sim \text{Multinomial}(1; \lambda)$$

and corresponding probability mass function $p(z_i\mid\lambda)$ which lets us write

$$p(y\mid z, \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{h=1}^H (f(y_i\mid\theta_h))^{z_{ih}}.$$

So far things seem clear. But then the authors write:

> The joint distribution of the observed data $y$ and the unobserved indicators $z$ conditional on the model parameters can be written
>   $$p(y, z\mid\theta,\lambda) = p(z\mid\lambda)p(y\mid z, \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{h=1}^H(\lambda_hf(y_i\mid\theta_h))^{z_{ih}}$$
>   with exactly one of $z_{ih}$ equaling $1$ for each $i$.

From the perspective of probability theory we can not just multiply
$p(y\mid z,\theta)$ and $p(z\mid\lambda)$, as the former is the *pdf* of a
*continous* random variable and the latter is the *pmf* of a *discrete* random
variable. On the other hand, we can multiply with priors for $\lambda$
and $\theta$, work out the full conditionals and get a working Gibbs
sampler.

So, my question is: What is $p(y, z\mid\theta,\lambda)$ as defined above, if it
is neither a pdf nor pmf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one year and a thorough course on probability later this seems kind of
obvious, but maybe the following sketch is still helpful for someone:

- Probability density functions and probability mass functions are the same
  kind of object. Both are a [Radon-Nikodym
  derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon-Nikodym_theorem) of a
  measure; in the case of the pdf with regard to ($n$-dimensional)
  Lebesgue-Measure, in the case of the pmf with regard to a counting measure.
- The general case of Bayes' theorem relates the prior distribution to the
  [Markov kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel) that is the
  posterior "distribution" by way of a Markov kernel for the conditional distribution of
  the observables given the parameters. This need not involve any density or
  likelihood functions at all.
- The densities for the prior distribution and for the conditional distribution
  of observables given parameters can very well be taken with regard to
  *different* dominating measures. In that case the joint distribution of
  observations and parameters has a density with regard to the [product
  measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) of the dominating
  measures.
- In my case this means $p(y, z\mid\theta,\lambda)$ is a density of the conditional
  distribution of $y$ and $z$ given $\theta$ and $\lambda$ with regard to the product of Lebesgue measure
  and a counting measure on $\{1,\dots,H\}$.